# Android: Google Place Autocomplete API giving "This ip, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API Key

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi I'm trying to add an autocompletion to the searchView in my android app - for locations. I created an android key for my app, with my sha1 key, but it still keeps giving me this error. Can somebody help me solve this issue, or give me another api to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Steps you need to follow are:

1) Go to the [google api console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

2) If you have already created a project then Go to the **services** tab and turn on **Places API**

3) Now go to API access and copy **Browser Key not the Android key**

4)Building the url to the web service like this:

```
 String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;
```

5) Where parameters are:

```
 String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;
```

and key is your browser key which you obtain from google console

Comment: Thanks so much if i could i would up vote you a billion times! You saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: any time bro :) @user2300851

Comment: Salute @Pankaj  plus one, I am trying this from the two day but not solved, after seen this answere and maily point  **Browser Key not the Android key** then i solved my question. thank you for saving my more wasted time. But i have one question **why we have to use Browser key , not android key here ?**